# Modify email sending macro to include attachment

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to modify this script to include an attachment in the email that it creates. Cell F5 on worksheet "Instructions" contains the file path. I've tried to modify it using information from several different sources.

Here is a working version, pre-attachment attempts:

```
Sub CreateMails()

     Dim objOutlook As Object
     Dim objMail As Object
     Dim rngTo As Range
     Dim rngSubject As Range
     Dim rngBody As String
     Dim rngAttach As Range
     Dim SigString As String

     Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

     With Worksheets("Data validation")
         Set rngTo = .Range("J63")
         Set rngSubject = .Range("J61")
         strbody = "One time vendor number request." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "Thank you," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "__________________________________" & vbNewLine & _
         .Range("J67") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "My Company" & vbNewLine & _
         "123 Address street" & vbNewLine & _
         "City, State, Zip, USA" & vbNewLine & _
         "Telephone:"

         End With

     With objMail
         .To = rngTo.Value
         .Subject = rngSubject.Value
         .Body = strbody
         .Save
     End With

     Set objOutlook = Nothing
     Set objMail = Nothing
     Set rngTo = Nothing
     Set rngSubject = Nothing
     Set strbody = Nothing
     Set rngAttach = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you should need is:

```
With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .Body = strbody
    .attachments.Add Range("F5").Value  'add the attachment
    .Save
End With
```

Using your code, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can share the below template code which i use for creating and attaching a sheet from my workbook as a PDF _ i've changed some of the "text" values but the rest is the same.

You could work with this to include the attachment, and send as xlsx if required.

```
Sub SendWorkSheetToPDF()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Dim SH As Worksheet

Dim cell As Range
Dim strto As String
Dim Strcc As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'To'
    For Each cell In      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail_addresses").Range("A2:A15")
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
        strto = strto & cell.Value & ";"
    End If
Next cell
If Len(strto) > 0 Then strto = Left(strto, Len(strto) - 1)
On Error Resume Next
'CC'
 For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail_addresses").Range("B2:B15")
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
        Strcc = Strcc & cell.Value & ";"
    End If
Next cell
If Len(Strcc) > 0 Then Strcc = Left(Strcc, Len(Strcc) - 1)
On Error Resume Next

Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
FileName = "afilename"
xIndex = VBA.InStrRev(FileName, ".")

If xIndex > 1 Then FileName = VBA.Left(FileName, xIndex - 1)
FileName = FileName & ".pdf"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileName
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutlookMail
.To = strto
.CC = Strcc
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "subject text"
.Body = "All," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Please see attached daily " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & _
    " "
 .Attachments.Add FileName
.Send
End With
Kill FileName
Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
MsgBox "Email Sent"
End Sub
```